# frame issue when creating a method in a class for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying to create a method I can reuse on multiple pages in my code for windows phone 8.1 universal Runtime app. So I copied this snippet from one of the pages into my helper class. However, I am struggling with "Frame" class. 
I also defined "Frame Frame;" outside of my method initially to get rid of the issue I saw when I copied the code initially.

Here is the method snippet:

```html
        public async void CheckAuthState(string pagename, string errormessage)
        {
            string rememberMeValue = (string)appRoamingSettings.Values["RememberMe"];

            if (rememberMeValue == "Yes")
            {
                //First check if the creds were saved
                //If saved,  check if the cookie is still valid (not past 2 days)
                //If still valid, get the cookie value to pass it in an object to the MC page
                //If not valid,  using the saved creds, go back and get a new cookie and then pass that to the MC page
                //Redirect to the MC page with the cookie in the object

                //Get the cookie value...
                string myCookieValue = (string)appRoamingSettings.Values["MyCookie"];

                //Get the original cookie obtain time....
                long CookieObtainedTimeValue = (long)appRoamingSettings.Values["CookieObtainedTime"];

                //Convertig date/time back to DateTime object....
                origCookieObtainedTime = DateTime.FromBinary(CookieObtainedTimeValue);

                currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

                //Check to see if cookie has expired....
                cookieTimeElasped = currentDateTime - origCookieObtainedTime;
                cookieTimeElapsedMins = cookieTimeElasped.TotalMinutes;

                //  2 days = 2880 mins but we give a margin of 1 minute
                if (cookieTimeElapsedMins <= 2879)
                {
                    //send the cookie to the MC page along with the cookie as an object
                    var shdCookie = myCookieValue;
                    var shdPageName = pagename;
                    // Create an object by populating the class with the data obtained from logging in and getting he cookie....
                    myCookiePageName myNeededSHDData = new myCookiePageName(shdCookie, shdPageName);

                    //Pass the object as a paramter to the Naviage method since we need to pass the parameters to the page being navigated to....
                    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MessageCenter), myNeededSHDData);
                }

                else
                {
                    //get a new cookie
                    //send the cookie to the MC page along with the cookie as an object

                    //Get the values for the userID and password from the settings....
                    string UserIDValue = (string)appRoamingSettings.Values["UserID"];
                    string PasswordValue = (string)appRoamingSettings.Values["Password"];

                    //Update the requestData string before sending.....
                    requestData = "{" + string.Format(RegisterRequestData, UserIDValue, PasswordValue) + "}";

                    string registerResults = await SHDAPI(registerUrl, requestData, errormessage);

                    if (registerResults != null)
                    {
                        // Get the cookie and the time and save it to settings
                        var shdCookie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SHDHelper.SHDObject>(registerResults).RegistrationCookie;
                        var shdPageName = pagename;

                        // Create an object by populating the class with the data obtained from logging in and getting he cookie....
                        myCookiePageName myNeededLoginData = new myCookiePageName(shdCookie, shdPageName);

                        //Pass the object as a paramter to the Naviage method since we need to pass the parameters to the page being navigated to....
                        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MessageCenter), myNeededLoginData);

                        // Stop showing the progress bar...      
                        mycontrols.progressbarNoShow(pgbar, pgText);

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // Stop showing the progress bar...
                        mycontrols.progressbarNoShow(pgbar, pgText);

                        //Show the error message...
                        ServerNetworkError.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
                    }

                }

            }

            else
            {
                //If NOT saved, then redirect to the SignIn page along with the page name..

                var shdCookie = "currentCookieValue"; //Putting some default value....
                var shdPageName = pagename;
                // Create an object by populating the class with the data obtained from logging in and getting he cookie....
                myCookiePageName myNeededSHDData = new myCookiePageName(shdCookie, shdPageName);

                //Instantiate the frames class for using in this function since this.Frame.Navigate can't be used...
                //Frame myframe = new Frame();

                //Frame Frame = new Frame();

                //Pass the object as a paramter to the Naviage method since we need to pass the parameters to the page being navigated to....
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SHDSignIn), myNeededSHDData);

            }



        }
```

My issue is that every time my code hits the "this.Frame" line it tell me Frame is null. I guess I am trying to see how to reference the same Frame that all my pages in app reference so I don't get this null? Or do I need to something else here to reference the proper frame?

Thanks

Comment: I think I see your misconception there: Every **Page** has a *Frame* Property, that hold the Frame-Instance which displays the page. You cannot just create a new Frame instance and use it's navigation methods (because that frame isn't displaying anything). If you want to use it in a helper class, you have to pass the original instance into there. Hope I'm not going to far with this but: Looks like you should read up on some basics about "object, class and instance" in OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Frame should be a shared instance within your app since it mantains the pages the app has navigated (your app's backstack which determines what page you see if any when pressing back button) so recreating a new one will not work.

Typically this is initialized in your `Application` class ("App" class in most new project wizard apps) and set to `Window.Current.Content`.  The same underlying instance is then also exposed by any `Page` instantiated in the app (navigated to by the Frame) as a `Frame` property in the `Page`.

So you can either reference it from anywhere via `Window.Current.Content` and then cast it to `Frame` or preferably it's something you pass as a parameter into your class (from either `Page.Frame`, an app wide definition that returns `Window.Current.Content` casted to `Frame`, or another class singleton instance that encapsulates `Frame` and is available app wide) that needs it via the class constructor or the specific class method that needs it.

Comment: Ok so I looked at your reply and also got some help from MSDN forums to get an answer... the solution as to refer to the app frame and then use that.... I used the following in my class:  `Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Object), Object);`  this resolved the issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you agree it's the answer which it sounds like you do, please mark my response as a useful answer.